# Python: k-means clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

I’m trying to use k-means clustering for the data of longitudes and latitudes of a .csv file but instead of plotting a graph I only want to get and print the centroids so that i can search them on google maps. Does anyone know how to code that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv


with open('fileName.csv', 'r') as infile:
  csv_reader = csv.reader (infile,  delimiter=',')
  x = []
  y = []

  for row in csv_reader:
    if row[3] != 'LONGITUDE':
      x.append(float(row[3]))
      y.append(float(row[4]))

    df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'y': y
    })
    #implement x and y in k-means and print the centroids
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the documentation of, for example, the Scikit Learn k-means clustering class https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html. When you have performed k-means clustering with that class it holds the cluster centres in the `cluster_centers_` attribute.

Comment: @Taxel just added the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the Shapely library.

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

# Easy way to read your csv file in
df = pd.read_csv('fileName.csv').rename(columns={'LONGITUDE': 'x', 'LATITUDE': 'y'})

# Assumes you have a column 'cluster_id' that references the cluster id for each coordinate
cluster_ids = df['cluster_id'].unique()
kmeans_clusters = []
for cluster_id in cluster_ids:

    # Filtered df for each cluster id    
    cluster_df = df.loc[df['cluster_id'] == cluster_id]
    x_values = cluster_df['x'].tolist()
    y_values = cluster_df['y'].tolist()

    xy_pairs = [point for point in zip(x_values, y_values)]
    kmeans_clusters.append(xy_pairs)

# Where kmeans_clusters is a list of your clusters, each containing a list of xy pairs
centroids = []
for cluster in kmeans_clusters:

    if len(cluster) > 1:
        # Create a convex hull, find the centroid
        convex_hull = MultiPoint(cluster).convex_hull
        centroid = convex_hull.centroid
        # Unpack to tuple object
        centroids.append(list(centroid.coords)[0])
    else:
        # Single point cluster, it is the centroid
        centroids.append(cluster[0])

print(centroids)
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me an error saying: " ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples"

Comment: I've updated the answer with a better method for finding the centroid of a cluster, and it accounts for single point clusters :)

Comment: The code runs but it still gives me a weird output :(( --> ['x', 'y'] it doesn't give me values. I just added what I've coded so far to the main post and I replaced "kmeans_cluster" with  "df" because that's where my x and y values are stored in my code. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I want it to give me the values of the centroids in the format of [ x,y ]

Comment: I've added support for your csv input - this provides a list of [x, y] outputs which is the centroid of each cluster, and assumes you have a cluster id set for each row.

Comment: Okay the "cluster_ids = df['cluster_id'].unique()" part doesn't work.. but thank you very much for your help:))) I don't want to bother you anymore I'll figure it out.

Comment: The reference to cluster_id assumes you have a column in your csv file that references what clusters each point belongs to, and has the column name "cluster_id". If my answer solves your issue, please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: The answers should be used to guide your final solution, not necessarily do all the work for you. Play around with the code, adapt it to your csv file and column names etc, assuming you have a cluster identifier for each point?